# Структуры моделей на go

Tags: файлы, golang, чистый-код

Свитчусь с шарпа на go. Если мой какой-то Service использует некоторые модели (к примеру, DTA-классы), я привык создавать рядом какую-нибудь папку Models и класть модели туда. Когда я пытаюсь провернуть что-то подобное на go, компилятор выражает свой протест. Отсюда 2 вопроса:

1. Могу ли я вообще организовать файлы таким образом, например: файл с "сервисом" лежит в директории .\service, файл модели: .\service\models\defaultModel.go?
2. В чем смысл помещать файлы модели рядом с сервисом? Их же может быть много, легко будет потеряться во всех файлах. Поделитесь из своей практики, как это принято организовывать

Comment: Как именно "выражает протест" компилятор? Ответ на вопрос 1 - да, можно.

Comment: Не дает использовать структуры и интерфейсы, объявленные в соседней папке models (пакет тот же)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаёшь папку service, и в её папку кладёшь файл service.go что-бы получилось как `service/service.go` после вся service будет доступна как

```
import (
  "github.com/youruser/yourapp/service"
)
```

стит помнить стандартные правила экпсортирования в golang что экспортируються только объекты которые начинаются с заглавной буквы.

к примеру

```
type Service struct {
}

func GetServices(): []Service {
}
```

Теперь будут доступны как

`service.GetServices()` и `service.Service{}`

А по поводу моделек, вообще глянь доку по gorm как они рекомендуют экспортировать модели. Я бы сказал что они предлагают практический идеальную структуру проекта.